# Isomorphism involving push forward of sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Let $S$ be any quasi-compact scheme and $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ on $S$ and $X = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ be its associated projective bundle with structure map $f : X \rightarrow S$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a quasi coherent sheaf on $X$. I am trying to show that $ f_{\ast} \mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} \mathcal{S}^{n}(\mathcal{E})  \cong f_{\ast} \mathcal{F}(n-1) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} \mathcal{E}$ for $n \geq 1$, where $\mathcal{S}^{n}(\mathcal{E})$ denote the $n$-th symmetric module.
Firstly, I am expecting it to be true. It is clear for $n=1$. But I don't know for higher $n$.

My try:

$f_{\ast} \mathcal{F}(n-1) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} \mathcal{E} \cong f_{\ast} \mathcal{F}(n-1) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{X}(1) \cong f_{\ast}( \mathcal{F}(n-1) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} \mathcal{O}_{X}(1) \cong f_{\ast}( \mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} \mathcal{O}_{X}(n)) \cong f_{\ast}( \mathcal{F}) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} f_{\ast}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(n)) \cong f_{\ast} \mathcal{F} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S}} \mathcal{S}^{n}(\mathcal{E}) $. The only problem I see in my proof is that pushforward functor need preserve tensor product of two sheaves. Can some one tell whether it is correct or not?

Any help would be great.

Comment: I would suggest trying it for $F=O(1)$. Then $f_*(O(1)\otimes_X O(1))=f_*(O(2))=S^2E$, while $f_*(O(1))=E$ and so the tensor produce is just $E\otimes_S E\neq S^2E$.

Comment: Then how should i prove or disprove my result?

Comment: Take $F=O(2)$ and $n=2$ in your question. Your isomorphism then becomes $S^2E\otimes_S S^2 E\equiv S^3E\otimes_S E$. Is this true?